# Auto-focusing problem on a Canon 500D with a EF-S 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6 IS(standard kit lens)

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus

I'm having problems with the lens. I've tried auto-focusing with my other lenses, and it works fine. It can only auto-focus one way, i.e. the focusing ring is still able to move, but only able to turn clockwise (i'm looking at the camera from the front).

Anyone with a similar problem or solution? Help! :(

Comment: Are you trying to autofocus or manually focus?  If autofocus, the focusing ring would be engaged by the motor and I don't think it would turn.  I supose you've checked the MF/AF switch?

Comment: i'm trying to auto-focus. it will move, but only one direction. >.< so i can focus in, but not out.

Comment: the switch is turned to AF.

Comment: So you can switch to MF and reset it, but in AF mode it will only go the one direction?  If so certainly sounds like a fault with the lens, not something you could fix by changing settings.

Comment: so i guess it's a trip to the service centre for me already. :o

Comment: anyone solved this issue without going to the service centre, please feel free to comment! :D

Comment: Just be careful about how much you pay to have it fixed, you can pick up a used EFS 18-55 for next to nothing (more than 10 sold for less than $60 on eBay this month alone, most of those for around $40) there are so many people trying to sell their kit lens after getting a better lens the market is saturated

Answer (score 3):

Its not clear that sending that lens in for service is worthwhile. If its new, warrantee service is fine, but the lens sells new for about $100, and the minimum service charge is likely to be $100.

Save up for a better lens, or if you have to, pick up a replacement.  The 50mm F1.8 is nearly as cheap and a much better lens (but its not a zoom).

I have the EFS 17-55 F2.8  and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe your reverse motor is stuck in the helix / bent plastic path. You need to push it to adjust.
   http://www.fotomozaic.ro/artikel.php?idstory=225&s=1
2. The motor has weak, broken gears.